# plaidml-setup uses the wrong lib path and gets OSErrors

Tags: macos, plaidml

I'm trying to install plaidml-keras on macOS High Sierra.
I followed the instruction guide:

```
pip install -U plaidml-keras
plaidml-setup
```

Then I got the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/bogao/anaconda3/envs/plaidml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/plaidml/__init__.py", line 154, in load_library
    return ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(libpath)
  File "/Users/bogao/anaconda3/envs/plaidml/lib/python3.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 426, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "/Users/bogao/anaconda3/envs/plaidml/lib/python3.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: dlopen(/Users/bogao/anaconda3/envs/plaidml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/plaidml/libplaidml.dylib, 6): image not found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/bogao/anaconda3/envs/plaidml/bin/plaidml-setup", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/bogao/anaconda3/envs/plaidml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/plaidml/plaidml_setup.py", line 16, in main
    ctx = plaidml.Context()
  File "/Users/bogao/anaconda3/envs/plaidml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/plaidml/__init__.py", line 892, in Context
    return plaidml.context.Context(_lib())
  File "/Users/bogao/anaconda3/envs/plaidml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/plaidml/__init__.py", line 789, in _lib
    _impl_lib = _Library()
  File "/Users/bogao/anaconda3/envs/plaidml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/plaidml/__init__.py", line 178, in __init__
    lib = load_library('libplaidml.dylib', ['lib'])
  File "/Users/bogao/anaconda3/envs/plaidml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/plaidml/__init__.py", line 166, in load_library
    return ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(libpath)
  File "/Users/bogao/anaconda3/envs/plaidml/lib/python3.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 426, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "/Users/bogao/anaconda3/envs/plaidml/lib/python3.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: dlopen(/Users/bogao/anaconda3/envs/plaidml/lib/libplaidml.dylib, 6): Symbol not found: ____chkstk_darwin
  Referenced from: /Users/bogao/anaconda3/envs/plaidml/lib/libplaidml.dylib (which was built for Mac OS X 10.15)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
 in /Users/bogao/anaconda3/envs/plaidml/lib/libplaidml.dylib
```

The actual file is at `/Users/bogao/anaconda3/envs/plaidml/lib/`
And plaidml is looking at `/Users/bogao/anaconda3/envs/plaidml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/plaidml/`

I also tried to use python venv, and got the same errors.
How could I get plaidml to use the correct path?

Comment: I've the same error. I didn't see your issue on Github? Have you tried to create an issue on Github? It still exist ?
Or this happens one month ago. Did you succeed to resolve the problem?

Comment: I didn't create an issue. I switched to another Mac and it worked perfectly. I guess it was more likely to be a Python environment issue rather than a plaidML problem. I was thinking reinstalling Anaconda might solve the problem, but I didn't try.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently getting the same error as the second one... (that occurred during handling the first)

I had also the first error, but it went away after running the following commands:

```
export PLAIDML_NATIVE_PATH=/Users/[username]/opt/anaconda3/envs/python/lib/libplaidml.dylib
export RUNFILES_DIR=/Users/[username]/opt/anaconda3/envs/python/share/plaidml
```

I am currently trying to figure out how to solve the second one. If someone has any ideas, here's link to GitHub issue that I created:
https://github.com/plaidml/plaidml/issues/1027

Comment: As you now, this worked: https://github.com/plaidml/plaidml/issues/1027#issuecomment-617032218