# Py2App>0.13 always outputs ValueError/ Py2App v0.13 App not opening on second machine

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, tkinter, py2app

So I finally got my python program working on my Mac (Catalina 10.15.4), but I am greeted with the following error when it is opened on another Mac (High Sierra 10.13.6.)

```
Could not import the PyAudio C module '_portaudio'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/dist/Riff Gen.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 355, in <module>
    _run()
  File "/Volumes/dist/Riff Gen.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 340, in _run
    exec(compile(source, path, 'exec'), globals(), globals())
  File "/Volumes/dist/Riff Gen.app/Contents/Resources/riffgen_v1.01.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pysine import sine
  File "pysine/__init__.pyc", line 14, in <module>
  File "pysine/pysine.pyc", line 1, in <module>
  File "pyaudio.pyc", line 116, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/Volumes/dist/Riff Gen.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_portaudio.so, 2): Symbol not found: ____chkstk_darwin
  Referenced from: /Volumes/dist/Riff Gen.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/libportaudio.2.dylib (which was built for Mac OS X 10.15)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
 in /Volumes/dist/Riff Gen.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/libportaudio.2.dylib
```

A simple tkinter test with various sounds and images works fine on the second machine, but not this script. I've tried adding all the packages manually, tried --nostrip, manually including 'libportaudio.2.dylib', and dozens of other ideas from countless outdated forums to no avail.

When the play function of my application is stripped, the app opens and crashes shortly thereafter - giving me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/RG no audio/Riff Gen.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 81, in <module>
    _run()
  File "/Volumes/RG no audio/Riff Gen.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 66, in _run
    exec(compile(source, path, 'exec'), globals(), globals())
  File "/Volumes/RG no audio/Riff Gen.app/Contents/Resources/riffgen_v1.01.py", line 2037, in <module>
    root.mainloop()
  File "tkinter/__init__.pyc", line 1277, in mainloop
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
Fatal Python error: PyEval_RestoreThread: NULL tstate
Current thread 0x00007fffa118e380 (most recent call first):
Abort trap: 6
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.
Deleting expired sessions...none found.
[Process completed]
```

I have been using Python 3.6 and Py2App v0.13 because it is, unfortunately, the only version that has successfully packaged my program in a standalone package. Any version later than 0.13 gives me the following error even when bundling in alias mode:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Alex/Desktop/python_scripts/rhythm_generator/riffgen/dist/Riff Gen.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 420, in <module>
    _run()
  File "/Users/Alex/Desktop/python_scripts/rhythm_generator/riffgen/dist/Riff Gen.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 414, in _run
    exec(compile(source, script, 'exec'), globals(), globals())
  File "/Users/Alex/Desktop/python_scripts/rhythm_generator/riffgen/riffgen_v1.01.py", line 7, in <module>
    from tkinter import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ValueError: character U+6573552f is not in range [U+0000; U+10ffff]
```

I've seen a handful of people with similar errors to the one above, but the few solutions I've seen had no success.

I'm assuming there is a simple solution to both of these errors, but after a long two weeks of tinkering, I'm out of ideas. I just began programming and *really* want to continue to deploy GUI programs, so I am desperate to get this functional. Any help is **greatly** appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Probably not an answer you were hoping for, but this might give you some ideas where to look:

- check if you don't have multiple pythons installed. Make sure you run it with 3.6. (but you probably already did)
- Check the modules installed on both PC's `help('modules')` in a python shell.
- Check if the correct version of the modules is installed. Install the exact same versions  `pip install SomePackage==1.0.4`
- `Symbol not found: ____chkstk_darwin` seems to be a very mac related issue. I'd start searching there in combination with the modules you use in your script. This is the only post I found on stackoverflow and it suggests looking at the PATH settings; [plaidml-setup uses the wrong lib path and gets OSErrors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60001795/plaidml-setup-uses-the-wrong-lib-path-and-gets-oserrors)

Comment: I have two versions, but I specified `python3` when packaging. And I suppose I'm confused about your suggestions regarding modules on each computer, seeing as my goal is to have a standalone `.app` that can be opened on a machine without python installed (like the second computer my friend is testing my programs on). I did try the link, but I was unable to pick much useful info that I understand, honestly.

Comment: I'm more concerned with the fact that everything was functional once the play function was stripped and it still crashed after a minute as this makes me think there is something fundamentally wrong with my code. I'm thinking `Symbol not found: ____chkstk_darwin` might be an error specific to v0.13, so I might have better luck targeting the third error first, then the second if it persists.